# Feather Texture Cylinder Vortex edge

Tags: texturing

[image]

How do I make it so its not just a hard edge of the vortex coming in, I know it has to do with the gradient node but I cant get it to work for me

[image]

Comment: Is your vortex-object geometry?  A tube?

Comment: Its a cylinder mesh without the caps and extended

Comment: So, you want a soft green -> blue transition to recede down the tube in the course of the animation?

Comment: See edit to my answer, if that's what you're after

Answer (score 1):

If you use the default UV-unwrap of your capless Cylinder, then its V should run 0-1, bottom to top.  Here, I'm using a Bevelled Curve, which, IMO, gives you more flexibility.. and so, (confusingly, sorry), it's the the U which runs from end to end.

Either way, choose your dimension, and plug its 0-1 into a color-ramp, for a gradient:

[image]

Then the colors will be mapped down it:

[image]

If rendering to a lossy format, you may have to watch out for the colors being quantized, creating banding-artefacts.

The attached .blend also includes a mechanism for looping the Noise in U and V, so an animation can be made without spatial or temporal seams:

[image]

thus:

[image]

If you wanted to animate the blue-green transition itself, that would just be a matter of key-framing an offset of the U coordinate. (The *Add* node, below):

[image]

For this sort of result:

[image]

[image]